# Partial Derivatives

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am trying to write an algorithm that will perform N-Dimensional mixed partial derivatives. I have an idea of what I need to be able to achieve, but **I cannot seem to come up with the correct loops/recursion that are required to realize the N-dimensional case**.

Here is the pattern for the first 4 dimensions:

```
| 1D  wzyx  | 2D           | 3D           | 4D           |
----------------------------------------------------------
| dx (0001) | dx    (0001) | dx    (0001) | dx    (0001) |
|           | dy    (0010) | dy    (0010) | dy    (0010) |
|           | dyx   (0011) | dyx   (0011) | dyx   (0011) |
|           |              | dz    (0100) | dz    (0100) |
|           |              | dzx   (0101) | dzx   (0101) |
|           |              | dzy   (0110) | dzy   (0110) |
|           |              | dzyx  (0111) | dzyx  (0111) |
|           |              |              | dw    (1000) |
|           |              |              | dwx   (1001) |
|           |              |              | dwy   (1010) |
|           |              |              | dwyx  (1011) |
|           |              |              | dwz   (1100) |
|           |              |              | dwzx  (1101) |
|           |              |              | dwzy  (1110) |
|           |              |              | dxyzw (1111) |
```

The number of derivatives for each dimension (because it follows a binary pattern) is (2^dim)-1; e.g., 2^3 = 8 - 1 = 7.

The derivative that is dyx is the dx value of the adjacent points in the y dimension. That holds true for all of the mixed partials. So that dzyx is dyx of the adjacent points in the z dimension. I'm not sure if this paragraph is relevant information for the question, just thought I'd put here for completeness.

Any help pointers suggestions are welcome. The part in bold is the part I need to realize.

**::EDIT::**

I'm going to to try and be a bit more explicit by providing an example of what I need. This is only a 2D case but it kind of exemplifies the whole process I think.

I need help coming up with the algorithm that will generate the values in columns dx, dy, dyx, et. al.

```
|  X  |  Y  | f(x, y) |  dx             |  dy       | dyx               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0  |  0  |    4    |  (3-4)/2 = -0.5 |  (3-4)/2  | (-0.5 - (-2.0))/2 |
|  1  |  0  |    3    |  (0-4)/2 = -2.0 |  (2-3)/2  | (-2.0 - (-2.0))/2 |
|  2  |  0  |    0    |  (0-3)/2 = -1.5 | (-1-0)/2  | (-1.5 - (-1.5))/2 |
|  0  |  1  |    3    |  (2-3)/2 = -0.5 |  (0-4)/2  | (-0.5 - (-0.5))/2 |
|  1  |  1  |    2    | (-1-3)/2 = -2.0 | (-1-3)/2  | (-1.5 - (-2.0))/2 |
|  2  |  1  |   -1    | (-1-2)/2 = -1.5 | (-4-0)/2  | (-1.5 - (-1.5))/2 |
|  0  |  2  |    0    | (-1-0)/2 = -0.5 |  (0-3)/2  | (-0.5 - (-0.5))/2 |
|  1  |  2  |   -1    | (-4-0)/2 = -2.0 | (-1-2)/2  | (-2.0 - (-2.0))/2 |
|  2  |  2  |   -4    |(-4--1)/2 = -1.5 |(-4--1)/2  | (-1.5 - (-1.5))/2 |
```

f(x, y) is unknown, only its values are known; so analytic differentiation is of no use, it must be numeric only.

Any help pointers suggestions are welcome. The part in bold is the part I need to realize.

**::EDIT - AGAIN::**

Started a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/1195522

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the list of (`0101` ...)?

Comment: i think this question is suitable for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @amod0017 I am going to post it there too I guess. I never heard of that site before now.

Comment: @Owen No I'm not really looking to be able to generate the binary part of it. I already have code that does that; some bit shifting solved that for me. I'm looking for an algorithm that allows me to calculate all of the derivatives.

Comment: @Ryan, well, if you take your bitstring and make a vector `e`, then find `|f(x + e) - f(x)| / |e|` that's the partial in that direction -- is that what you're looking for?

Comment: There's a C++ library called GiNaC that does symbolic math, perhaps that would be helpful? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiNaC

Comment: @Ryan its more suitable there its a stack site only.. however you can also prefer the Programmer stack site as well http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, programmers.se is for professional programmers and issues they deal with. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I envy you getting to work on fun problems like this one.

Comment: @amod0017 If it's not in the form of a winnable contest, it's not really suitable for codegolf.se

Comment: @Gareth... ok.. i thought this question is more on to program logical hence i prefer it for that.

Comment: 1. Your formula for the derivative at the boundaries of the domain doesn't look right. Why divide by 2? 2. If you need `dxdy`, then presumably you need `dx^2` and `dy^2` too. And mutatis mutandis for higher dimensions. 3. With such a small sample size, third derivatives and above (`dzyx` etc in your notation) will all be zero. Is your real sample size bigger?

Comment: If you just have points, and don't actually have f, you can't possibly compute any differentials. (I know, I know, all floats are discrete, but if you can't work down in increasing precision to find the differential, and your values of f are at constant increments of one unit, it's just a joke to think of that as a differential.) Are we told that f is analytic, or better smooth?

Comment: @TonyK I'll agree that the steps taken at the edges are not exactly "correct". But in the actual data set the boundary values are padded such that there will be extra data at the end points. e.g., if we are only interested in the interval from 1..4 we will provide extra points -1..1 && 4..6 so that the central difference method is still valid over the interval of 1..4. Then even if some of the derivatives of the points in -1..1 or 4..6 are erroneous it won't matter cause they won't be used.

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson Agreed it is only an approximation of the function; but this is a valid method of achieving the derivative. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Definition_via_difference_quotients WARNING PDF: http://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math344/lecture27.pdf

Comment: @Ryan The page you link to (and lecture) are quite clear: if the error is O(h), and h is fixed at 1 as in here, your inability to iterate with decreasing values of h is a real problem. Equally spaced increments of f are useless: O(h) might be a constant error of a million because the real f wobbles near each unit. Whatever you're trying to calculate, with only f(0,0), f(0,1) and no f(0.5,0), f(0.25,0) etc it's not an acceptable estimate for the derivative unless you have a lot of extra order/smoothness information given about f.

Comment: @Nicholas you seem to be laboring under the delusion that this is the actual data set; what is more the error for the central difference mthod is O(h^2) not O(h). The error of the function is proportional to the step-size; but it is assumed that in practice the stepsize is indeed small enough to capture significant instantaneous changes. http://bit.ly/r1njO6 However, I am not asking how to calculate the derivative or the error. I need help implementing an algorithm that allows me hit each point in a set and perform an action there. If you are un-able/willing to do so please cease and desist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, I think the following can work:

```
function partial_dev(point, dimension):
    neighbor_selector = top_bit(dimension)
    value_selector = dimension XOR neighbor_selector
    prev_point = point_before(point,neighbor_selector)
    next_point = pointafter(point,neighbor_selector)
    if value_selector == 0:
        return (f[prev_point] - f[next_point])/2
    else:
        return ( partial_dev(prev_point, value_selector) -
                 partial_dev(next_point, value_selector) )/2
```

The idea is: your top bit of the dimension value is the coordinate in which the before and after points are selected. If the rest of the dimension value is 0, you use the `f` values for the point for partial derivative calculation. If it is not, you get the partial derivative represented by the rest of the bits to calculate the values.

If you need all the values of all the dimension values calculated, then you don't need recursion at all: just use the dimension selector as an array index, where each array element contains the full value set for that dimension. The array is initialized such that `vals[0][coords] = f(coords)`. Then you calculate `vals[1]`, `vals[2]`, and when calculating `vals[3]`, you use `vals[1]` as the value table instead of `vals[0]` (because 3 = `0b11`, where neighbor selector is `0b10` and value_selector is `0b01`).

Comment: I'm working on actually implementing this right now. But I have marked it as the answer now. I'll update the gist linked to in the question with the actual implemented code.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is cleanly solved by functional programming. Indeed, \partial_{xy}f is the partial derivative along x of \partial_y f.

I suppose you have a black box function (or function object) `f`, taking its values as a pointer to a memory buffer. Its signature is assumed to be

```
double f(double* x);
```

Now, here is a code to get the (second order finite difference) partial derivative to f:

```
template <typename F>
struct partial_derivative
{
    partial_derivative(F f, size_t i) : f(f), index(i) {}

    double operator()(double* x)
    {
        // Please read a book on numerical analysis to tweak this one
        static const double eps = 1e-4;

        double old_xi = x[index];
        x[index] = old_xi + eps;
        double f_plus = f(x);

        // circumvent the fact that a + b - b != a in floating point arithmetic
        volatile actual_eps = x[index];
        x[index] = old_xi - eps;
        actual_2eps -= x[index]
        double f_minus = f(x);

        return (f_plus - f_minus) / actual_2eps;
    }

private:
    F f;
    size_t index;
};

template <typename F>
partial_derivative<F> partial(F f, index i)
{
    return partial_derivative<F>(f, i);
}
```

Now, to compute \partial_{123}f, you do:

```
boost::function<double(double*)> f_123 = partial(partial(partial(f, 0), 1), 2);
```

If you need to compute them all:

```
template <typename F>
boost::function<double(double*)> mixed_derivatives(F f, size_t* i, size_t n_indices)
{
    if (n_indices == 0) return f;
    else return partial(mixed_derivatives(f, i + 1, n_indices - 1), i[0]);
}
```

and so you can do:

```
size_t indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
boost::function<double(double*)> df_123 
    = mixed_derivatives(f, indices, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(size_t));
```

Comment: I have up-voted this answer, because I think it works. I don't really understand boost::function though, therefore I'm not really sure how I could make this work for an unknown number of dimensions. Also, I do not know the function so the assumption of `double f(double* x)` is invalid. All I have is an array of points that represent the output from a function.

Answer (score 1):

It sure seems like you could just have a loop based on the dimension (number of binary places), and then recurse down to the next binary digit.

Rough (not C++) Pseudocode:

```
Function partialcalc(leadingdigit, dimension)

  If dimension > 1 {
    For i = 1 to dimension {
      //do stuff with these two calls
      partialcalc(0, i - 1)
      partialcalc(1, i - 1)
    }
  }
  Else {
    //partialcalc = 1D case
  }

return partialcalc

End Function
```

The way recursion works is that you have a problem, where it can be broken down into subproblems that are equivalent to the larger problem, just smaller.  So since you're using all the binary digits to the dimensioneth place, then you just do the calculation on the top dimension by recursing to two subproblems based on the 0 and 1 value in the dimension digit.  The bottom of the recursion is the dimension = 1 level.  Since you emphasize that you only need to figure out how to structure the loop recursion, and already have the math figured out, this structure should work for you.

Comment: If someone wants to whip this into C++ shape, go for it.  It's been too long for me.

Comment: Lance I'm sorry I don't see what `leadingdigit` does in this code? Also, how does it know where to get the data from and where to put the data once the calculations are completed?

Comment: @Ryan, `leadingdigit` is the first (leftmost) binary digit for the dimension level, so it solves for all `0` digits first, recursing down, then it solves for all `1` digits, recursing down.  The `stuff` is where you do the stuff you've already figured out on how to generate the data.  While in VBA I would use redefining arrays to store the data, I imagine in C++ you'd use some type of pointer structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make a start with the answers, my first thought would be to interpolate with Chebyshev Polynomials.  The approximation can then easily be differentiated (or integrated).

The [Gnu Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/Chebyshev-Approximations.html) has an implementation.

Note, I am not an expert on Numerical Methods, and so I can't explain the problems with this method.  However, it should work well enough if you want a local approximation.  If someone knows better, feel free to downvote.

Comment: I use Chebyshev polynomials in my physics research, and this seems like a nice suggestion to me.

Comment: I am sure Chebyshev polynomials are great at performing derivatives. But that does not really address the issue of being able to compute N-dimensional derivatives. The derivative is not the concern.

Comment: Chebyshev polynomials are for 1D functions. Also "it should work well enough if you want a local approximation" misses the point: Chebyshev approximation is useful when you want a global approximation.